# How to Import data from a pc or mac

Tags: iphone, objective-c, import

I would like to enable the user to import data from an xml file on my iPhone app. I have already implemented an import from a web url. I also implemented fileURLWithPath to get the file locally from my mac during development, however, I believe, that works only on the simulator as far as I know, as the simulator is actually a mac process and has all the access permissions of a usual mac application, which is not the case, when I run it on the iPhone device, correct?

Thanks already for any suggestions.

René

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fileURLWithPath: will work on an iOS device if you make sure that the path is inside your app's sandboxed file subdirectory, for instance the app's Documents directory that is shared with iTunes file sharing access.

Comment: ok, however, my app is not yet appearing in the list of apps to share files with iTunes. I have other apps installed on my iPhone, which appear. I guess I have to tell iTunes somehow, that my app is also able to transfer data, so it will be visible in the supported apps section for file transfer?

Comment: Found the answer myself: Adding the key <key>UIFileSharingEnabled</key><true/> in the info.plist will resolve the issue and app will be able to share any files.